# Authorize Azure API Connection using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell

I want to write a PowerShell to Authorize my API connection, but not sure which command and modules need to be used

[image]

I looked into this [link](https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppConnectionAuth) but it's 4 years old and does not work with the current .NET core Powershell module even I replaced AzureRM to AZ. It gives an error

```
New-AzResource: InvalidRequestContent : The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'The 'id' property '' under 'properties.api' is not valid.'.
CorrelationId: 60e1aac0-dc0e-4e56-95b7-852bbbac60ff
```

It will be great if someone can guide me to write the required PowerShell script to authorize my API connection

Comment: I am not very clear about what you want to authorize and what its purpose is, can you describe it more clearly? In addition, there are some problems with your link, please update it correctly

Comment: @FrankGong I am trying to create an API connection in logic app , as in logic app it ask to authorize the connection ,which i have to do manually. My requirement is to automate the API authorization using the powershell script.  Till the time the connection is not authroized the logic app complains about the connection and it says unauthorized connection .

Comment: @FrankGong updated the link https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppConnectionAuth

Answer (score 0):

While not documented enough, there is [an ARM REST Endpoint to fetch the Consent Links](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/b116b8a589e9771b05736c07c8caaa17c1eabfa6/specification/web/resource-manager/Microsoft.Web/stable/2016-06-01/logicAppsManagementClient.json#L907) which is used by the portal (and was leveraged by the PowerShell script).

But note that you will only get consent links which you will have to open and authorize. The PowerShell script that you shared aims to open the consent link in the local browser which if already logged in should return without any action.

If this script is run on a machine that maintains valid sessions for all required oauth connections, it is possible to automate their deployment this way. **But** this *might* fail for any account/service that requires 2FA.